# Homotopy Equivalences of Spaces?

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm learning about homotopy equivalences of spaces.

In this example, what I don't understand is that, while the codomain of the function $H(y,t)$ is $Y$, isn't it the case that $H(y,1)=g(y)$ is a function of co-domain $X$? Shouldn't the co-domain always be $Y$?

[image]

Similarly, in the next example, doesn't h(x,t) have co-domain X, but h(x,0)=r(x) have co-domain A?

[image]

Comment: Since $X\subset Y$, a map with codomain $X$ can always be regarded as a map with codomain $Y$.

Comment: I see! Thanks! I was looking at X and Y as entirely different spaces.

Comment: Are there homotopies between spaces X and Y such that X $\not\subset$ Y and Y $\not\subset$ X? If yes, does it mean that the definition of H can't take the same advantage as above?

Comment: Yes, there are, in those cases the image is always a subset of $Y$. But commonly you've got the inclusion.